# Laravel sanctum how to check token for all api requests?

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have an rest api `/api/example`
need to provide different json information for authorized and unauthorized users.
If I use the standard `middleware('auth:sanctum')` then the user who has the token will get the information, but the user without it will get the `401 Unauthorized`. With this approach, it is necessary to create two different routes for each request 1. without protection 2 with protection. It is not comfortable. Is there a way that when I request with a token, I would receive protected information, and without a token, the usual information, accessible to all users?

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->post('/example', ExampleController::class );
```

Comment: do you have '/user' ?

Comment: @KarlMounguengui No, this is not a standard route, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own middleware that checks and grabs the bearertoken and set the user if its passed sanctum guard, and would never return 401 response

e.i.

```
php artisan make:middleware GuestOrAuth
```

then on `app/Http/Middleware/GuestOrAuth.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class GuestOrAuth {
    
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {

        if ( $request->bearerToken() && Auth::guard('sanctum')->user() ) 
            Auth::setUser( Auth::guard('sanctum')->user() );
            
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

then assign that on `$routeMiddleware` inside `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    .
    .
    .
    'guest.or.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\GuestOrAuth::class
];
```

then you can use `guest.or.auth` instead of `auth:sanctum`

```
Route::middleware('guest.or.auth')->get('/logged', function() {
    return auth()->user() ?? ['message' => 'No Valid User!'];
});
```